# I get "FirebaseError: could not read archive: response exceeded harpoon max page size" when running "firebase ext:install ."

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to install my own Firebase Extension for my Firebase project. I run

```
firebase ext:install .
```

But I get this error:

```
$ firebase ext:install .
i  extensions: ensuring required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  extensions: required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  extensions: Checking project IAM policy...
✔  extensions: Project IAM policy OK
✔  Uploaded extension source code
✖  Archiving and uploading extension source code

Error: Failed to archive and upload extension source from ., FirebaseError: could not read archive: response exceeded harpoon max page size

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had in the folder an example app (written with Flutter) which resulted into too many files:

```
example/
functions/
CHANGELOD.md
extension.yaml
POSTINSTALL.md
PREINSTALL.md
```

I created a separated `extension` folder without the example folder:

```
example/
extentsion/
  functions/
  CHANGELOD.md
  extension.yaml
  POSTINSTALL.md
  PREINSTALL.md
```